# best method for getting image ID from Instagram

Tags: php, image, api, xpath, instagram

I am writing an app that gets analytical data from Instagram though it requires the submission of the of the image ID.

Though the image ID from instagram can appear in various xpaths and various naming prefixes
this example shows the image ID with the word 'frame' in front of it

[image: instagram image ID]

is there a ready made solution to retrieving an Instagram imageID.

What might be the best approach if I needed to write one my self?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: @nomistic  the working code is very irrelevant to the question. This is a brand new function I need to create and the language has not even been chosen yet. I thought about Scrapy but the xpath is always different. Scrapy needs an XPath. I pondered using file_get_contents("") and somehow squeeze the image properties out, but drawing a blank from there because of the variable xpaths..

Comment: Voting to close. It's even unclear whether you are asking for a tool/ library recommendation (which is off-topic here) or a full solution, which is too broad.

Comment: @MathiasMüller to broad? It would be to broad if there were many solutions. to date I have only come up with 1 and that is the have the image submitted via your own system. When you POST an image, you get the imageID in the return JSON. But this isn't going to work because I need data from images already posted.

Comment: Isn't there an API to get an image URL from Instagram? (Not used Instagram myself, I guess my answer is that if this does exist, it will be in the developer docs on the Instagram website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open the image in gramfeed.com, it will have media ID that can be copied.

For example if https://instagram.com/p/2WbeH-BQTx/ is the image you want, replace http://instagram.com with http://gramfeed.com

http://gramfeed.com/p/2WbeH-BQTx/ will open the same image with more details, you will have to login via instagram on gramfeed.

There is an Instagram API available to get this programatically: https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media_by_shortcode

Comment: I had completely missed the shortcode API call. Thank you!